# Merging two SQL statement in one , to update a row in a table if it meet certain conditions

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am working on an app using JDBC to update stocks and place order.

I am storing the products and I want to update the products if the quantity requested is less then the stored one , and I want to delete the product from the database if the quantity is equal to the number of current stock in the DB.

I am using two different statements, but I would like to use just one of them. For example, if I want to add an order into the DB the things that are going to be requested by the system are a name and product quantity. The product quantity would get subtracted from the total quanitity of the product on the DB. The pseudocode would be

```
IF product quantity - user quantity =0 THEN DELETE product FROM database

ELSE UPDATE product quantity TO product quantity-user quantity ON THE database

product quantity=quantity of the product in the database

user quantity=quantity requested by the user
```

The Prepared Statements that I have for now are these two

```
UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity-? WHERE product_name=?

DELETE FROM products WHERE product_name=?
```

I would like to merge them as one if possible

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You can't do a delete and an update in the same statement.  What is wrong with controlling this flow from your Java code?

Comment: You have two completely different behaviors (remove row or not).  This will not be pretty or easy to maintain. 

Look into the SQL Dialect for your database on how to do conditionals. You might be able to. Otherwise look into stored procedures.

Comment: Why would you want to delete a product?

Comment: @Strawberry  because if the product is no longer available, so it could not be ordered, other option would be to use a condition if the product quantity is less then a certain number

Comment: Presumably you have code in place which prohibits an order if the order quantity is greater than that in stock. And you wouldn't want to lose inventory if the quantity in stock falls below the minimum allowed order quantity. -Though perhaps this is ok for what looks like a homework question.

Comment: Just because it's not presently available, it seems strange that you would want to eradicate the fact that it even ever existed.

Answer (score 0):

In a production system you would do this sort of thing.

For an order, as you said, do this.

```
UPDATE products SET quantity=quantity-? WHERE product_name=?
```

Then, in an overnight or weekly cleanup do this to get rid of rows with no quantity left.

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE quantity = 0
```

When you want to know what products are actually available, you do

```
SELECT product_name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 0
```

The concept here: rows with zero quantity are "invisible" even if they aren't deleted.

If this were my system, I would not DELETE rows. For one thing, what happens when you get more products in stock?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to loosen security by setting the MySQL [Configuration Property](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) `allowMultiQueries` to `true` in the connection URL.

Then you can execute two SQL statements together:

```
String sql = "UPDATE products" +
               " SET quantity = quantity - ?" +
             " WHERE product_name = ?" +
               " AND quantity >= ?" +
             ";" +
             "DELETE FROM products" +
             " WHERE product_name = ?" +
               " AND quantity = 0";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setInt(1, userQuantity);
    stmt.setString(2, productName);
    stmt.setInt(3, userQuantity);
    stmt.setString(4, productName);
    stmt.execute();
    int updateCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
    if (updateCount == 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Product not available: " + productName);
    // if you need to know if product got sold out, do the following
    stmt.getMoreResults();
    int deleteCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
    boolean soldOut = (deleteCount != 0);
}
```